# npm install weird behavour: pngquant pre-build test failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, pngquant

When I try to install `npm install` using continuous integration I'm getting following error:

```
⚠ The `/home/jenkins/workspace/dev/node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant` binary doesn't seem to work correctly
  ⚠ pngquant pre-build test failed
  ℹ compiling from source
  ✔ pngquant pre-build test passed successfully
  ✖ Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed
```

`Libpng-dev, make, gcc` already installed on Ubuntu 18.10.

Here are the package.json contents

https://gist.github.com/turalus/10877da878b9bb0f5c4898fa16fa6fb1

There is no prevention for npm install not to run smoothly but it doesn't recognize libpng-dev.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are they installed globally or locally? Because those packages that are run using the cmd need to have a `$PATH` pointing to the nose_modules

Comment: pngquant is installed globally. Libpng-dev, make, gcc are installed using root user

Comment: I assume they are installed in some package?

Comment: @JonasWilms I don't quite get what do you mean

Comment: You did `npm install` in some folder right?

Comment: @JonasWilms yes, here "/home/jenkins/workspace/dev/"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191611/discussion-between-demonoid-and-jonas-wilms).

Comment: @JonasWilms yes inside, /home/jenkins/workspace/dev/